# Is there a way to automatically determine the possible exceptions a statement could throw?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, exception, intel

Is there a methodology -- and if so, what is it -- for finding out what exceptions may be thrown by a particular statement?

e.g., given the following code:

```
String substr = SelectedFileName.Substring(DATE_BEGIN_POS, DATE_LENGTH);
return DateTime.Parse(substr);
```

...how would I know what exception[s] might be thrown by the second line? You would think one could highlight the line, and select something from the context menu to supply this/these...

Comment: @Mike: Maybe you should work on self control <g>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there isn't a way of finding this out other than looking on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

The easy/lazy/C# way of doing this would just to "catch (Exception e)" and deal with it as the generic exception type.  You have all of the information you need in that type for most exceptions anyway.  Exception handling should only really be used for logging/promoting, so IMHO knowing that your DateTime.Parse can throw either a FormatException or ArguementNullException is pointless (to me).

Comment: MSDN is notoriously incomplete -- many things will throw more types of exceptions than is what is listed.

Comment: Indeed... Perhaps MSDN should open it doors up to user edits, so it becomes more like a community wiki rather than "We are Microsoft, see our failures!"